# Cambiar parametro de un activity desde un servicio

Tags: android, android-studio, hilos

Estoy en mis primeros pasos en Android Studio, ya sé algunas cosas básicas como crear `Activities`, colocar objetos en ellas y pasar de una a otra.

Ahora tengo una duda y quisiera su ayuda, por favor.

Tengo un activity que tiene un par de elementos. Además de la activity `juego.xml` - `juego.java` tengo un servicio `reloj.java` que quiero que me controle algunas propiedades de la activity después de cierto tiempo.

Mis preguntas son dos:

1. ¿Cómo hago para cambiarle las propiedades a un elemento (`Button`, `Layout`, `TextView`) en un activity desde un servicio? ¿Cómo hago la instrucción para referenciar el elemento y la propiedad (color fondo, visibilidad) que quiero cambiar?

He intentado con algo así pero no ha funcionado:

```
layout.figura.background=(FF00FF00FF);
layout.setVisibility(figura.INVISIBLE);
```

2. ¿Cómo hago para ver el segundero `i` del `sleep` en el `TextView` reloj?

A continuación, el código relevante.

> Fichero XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/figura"
    android:text="COLOR"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark">
</LinearLayout>

<texview
    android:id="@+id/reloj"
    android:text="i"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"/>
```

> Método

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    if(workerThread == null || !workerThread.isAlive()){
        workerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i>0; i++){

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep( 30000 );
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                   // layout.figura.background=(FF00FF00FF)
                  // layout.setVisibility(figura.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });
        workerThread.start();
    }
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes llamar desde `onHandleIntent()` un método el cual enviaría un valor a tu Activity, este sería tu servicio:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {


    protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

       //Cambia color 
        changeColor()

    }

   private void changeColor() {

        Intent sendLevel = new Intent();
        sendLevel.setAction("CHANGE_COLOR"); 
        sendLevel.putExtra( "COLOR","#00FF00");
        sendBroadcast(sendLevel);


   }

}
```

En tu `Activity` un `BroadCastReceiver` obtendrìa el color y lo asignaría como ejemplo a un `TextView`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

   MyReceiver receiver;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

      //Registra
      receiver = new myService();
      registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("CHANGE_COLOR"));      
   }

   //Desregistra.
   @Override
   public void onStop(){
       super.onStop();
       unregisterReceiver(receiver);          
   }

  class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Recive color.
       if(intent.getAction().equals("CHANGE_COLOR")){
          String colorRecibido = intent.getIntExtra("COLOR", "#000");

        //Asigna a TextView.              
       textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colorRecibido));

       }
   }

}
```

Comment: Gracias por el código y la explicación, muy claros.

Comment: Dada mi ignorancia tengo una duda, yo hice el servicio con un SERVICE que funciona de forma infinita en un hilo diferente en el que funciona la APP.  ¿Cuándo se necesita un servicio infinito en un hilo aparte, es mejor usar SERVICE o INTENTSERVICE?

Comment: ¿Para que el INTERSERVICE que sugieres funcione de forma infinita y dispare el cambio de color, cada cierto tiempo debo hacer lo siguiente?           
                                           for (int i = 1; i>0; i++){

                    try{
                        Thread.sleep( 30000 );
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

       //Cambia color
         changeColor()  

               }  Cómo hago para que contador (i) del  FOR aparezca en el texview